# JQuery Flexigrid: How to wrap text in flexigrid column?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

JQuery Flexigrid: How to wrap text in flexigrid column?

Comment: I think you would have to modify the css but I'm not sure on this one would like to know myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(table).flexigrid({
    nowrap: false
});
```

Add the param "nowrap" and set it to false.